# Сдвинуть положение шапки с использованием vaadin

Tags: frontend, framework, vaadin

Не так давно начал использовать фреймоворк vaadin. Стоит задача изменения положения шапки на странице сайта. Т.е. сначала должна идти карусель, а потом шапка. Но в данный момент идет сначала шапка, а потом карусель.
И есть ли возможность изменения цвета шапки?

```
AppLayout appLayout = new AppLayout();
    AppLayoutMenu menu = appLayout.createMenu();
    menu.addMenuItems(
            new AppLayoutMenuItem(VaadinIcon.USER.create(), "Рейтинг", ""),
            new AppLayoutMenuItem(VaadinIcon.TRENDING_UP.create(), "Занятия", ""),
            new AppLayoutMenuItem(VaadinIcon.TRENDING_UP.create(), "Экз", ""),
            new AppLayoutMenuItem(VaadinIcon.USER.create(), "Профиль", ""),
            new AppLayoutMenuItem(VaadinIcon.USER.create(), "Выйти", ""));

    VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout(appLayout);
    verticalLayout.setPadding(false);
    verticalLayout.setSpacing(false);
    add(verticalLayout, appLayout);
    setPadding(false);
    setSpacing(false);
```

Comment: Это не код выхода.

Comment: @VladimirRodichev а какую часть кода от меня нужно? Благодаря этой части я смог создать шапку, но мне ее нужно переместить

Comment: дай лучше ссылку сайта

Comment: @VladimirRodichev сайта нет, проект на localhost. Могу только скриншот приложить к комментарию (https://imgur.com/rtSHb01)

Comment: открой в браузере инспектор и посмотри код.

Comment: @Dmitry, не слушайте Владимира. Он по всей видимости никогда не работал с Vaadin. Относительно положения меню. Я буду вынужден вас огорчить, но с данным кодом уже нельзя ничего сделать чтобы изменить положение меню. Дело в том, что Вы используете вспомогательный компонент AppLayout. На самом деле это всего лишь шаблон c некоторыми вспомогательными классами, вроде меню. И в данном случае положение меню фиксировано. И в данном коде вы всего лишь определяете состав меню - и все. Код отвечающий за Его же размещение лежит внутри компонента AppLayout.

Comment: Лично я всегда создавал все шаблоны для Vaadin вручную. Там Вы сможете  контролировать абсолютно все.

Comment: однако у меня есть еще идеи с помощью которых можно переместить меню. Это наследоваться от AppLayout и там уже повлиять на положение меню. к сожалению у меня нет времени на описание создания шаблона и на наследование если честно тоже. но если у меня появится время то я могу попробовать в конце недели провести эксперимент с переопределением положения меню в AppLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сменить цвет шапки можно вызвать .getStyle().set("color", "нужный цвет")